# Is there a possibility to make a nav for every page. So when i edit 1 it changes for all?

Tags: html, css

For my school I have to work 1 month in a company. I'm making a website and one of the requirements is that I only make 1 Navigation that I use on every HTML page.

Obviously I want to do it myself without asking the company to help me, but after looking an hour i didn't really find a good solution.

I rode some stuff about php, but whenever I add it in my HTML it doesn't do anything. Someone that could help me?

One Nav HTML Page for all my HTML Pages so when I edit 1 thing it changes for every HTML Page.

Comment: Not with a pure html. Have to use a programming language like PHP using include/require

Comment: If you're doing it with PHP look into master pages. And include your separate pages in amongst your Nav, header & footer

Comment: You'd want to use php include. https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp

Comment: @Khaled never recommend w3schools for PHP - it's a terrible resources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could maybe get it working with `<iframe>` i believe i used that back in the day for a site (code was so dirty looking)
I would recommend using php, your directory would look like this

```
map
|-index.php
|-nav.php
```

Inside the index.php you want to use [include](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp)

## index.php

```
<html>
<body>
<?php include 'nav.php'; ?>
<h1>super awesome site</h1>
</body
</html>
```

## nav.php

```
<nav>
my nav bar
</nav>
```

Now because you are using php you can't just open the file in your web browser, you will need to run a web server directed to this file or use `php -S localhost:8080` to start a local test server in the current directory
if you have any questions don't hesitate to ask

edit: put nav.php in qoutes

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP

```
<?php
    include 'nav.php';
    //body
?>
```

Get Started with PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php

Install PHP: https://www.cloudways.com/blog/how-to-start-php-programming/

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do you custom nav in a separated HTML file and attached it to every page of your website and for the PHP to work

your file should be .php file and placed on a server which is created to run php files such as Apache server.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Welcome to my home page!</h1>
<p>Some text.</p>
<p>Some more text.</p>
<?php include 'footer.php';?>

</body>
</html>
```

as you see here the footer is seprated HTML file which u can use at every page of your project :).